Looker: providing specific values for a dimension filter within a specific Explore
I’m wondering if there’s a way that I can only have specific values appear in my drop down when filtering on a specific field in a certain explore?
So for example, I have the field Dimension 1 (has 156 unique values) that can be filtered on in multiple explores (Explore A, Explore B, Explore C, etc), but I only want the specific values relevant to a given Explore to appear when someone jumps into that Explore and filters on Dimension 1. Is there a way that I can only have specific values appear in my dropdown when filtering on Dimension 1 while I’m in Explore A, a different set of values when in Explore B and so on?

For this dimension to show up in all these different Explores, do all Explores point to same Looker View as well?
